# Performance while adding subviews is O(n^2) if window has tintColor set

Tags: ios, ios9

If you set `tintColor` on the `UIWindow` level (to let all views inherit it), `addSubview` has O(n^2) performance. That means if you add a significant number of subviews to any single parent view you can get extremely bad performance.

As a test, if you add 6000 subviews under these conditions it takes over 10 minutes to add them all. If you don't set a `tintColor` adding that many subviews takes well under 1 second.

Bug filed as rdar://problem/25934331

What are the possible workarounds for now?

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be mitigated in at least two ways:

1. Clear the `tintColor`, add the subviews, then immediately set the `tintColor` back to its original value. This usually won't be visible on-screen if you do it in the same runloop iteration.
2. Explicitly set the `tintColor` on the subviews you are adding. In that case it doesn't seem to trigger the problem.